# I get neither output, nor an error using np.linalg.pinv

Tags: numpy, matrix

I have tried this and it worked fine:

```
phi = np.zeros((len(traindata),3))
phi[:,0] = 1
phi[:,1] = traindata[:,0] 
phi[:,2] = traindata[:,1] 

Wml = np.dot(np.dot((np.linalg.pinv(np.dot((phi.T),phi))),(phi.T)), y_train)
print Wml, "weight selection"


[[ -1.08778441e+01]
[ -3.61672723e-02]
[ -4.38518378e-03]] weight selection
```

But when I try the same with more columns as the following:

```
phi = np.zeros((len(traindata),5))
phi[:,0] = 1
phi[:,1] = traindata[:,0] 
phi[:,2] = traindata[:,1] 
phi[:,3] = traindata[:,2] 
phi[:,4] = traindata[:,3] 

Wml = np.dot(np.dot((np.linalg.pinv(np.dot((phi.T),phi))),(phi.T)), y_train)
print Wml, "weight selection"
```

I did not obtain any result or error. Am I missing something or am I doing something wrong? I have tried with different datasets and different sizes and it seems that it works fine until 3 columns but from 4 columns nothing shows up.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: nothing at all, no output, no error, just blank line. I have been trying different sizes and it seems that until 2D data it works fine, but 3D and so on, I get nothing.

Comment: I think it should show an error but it is not shown because if I write more code afterwards (just something like print "this") it is not there either